# How to implement a rotating draggable icons UI?

Tags: android, android-animation

The image attached is the requirement for the application's UI - consisting of a group of icons that need to rotate, like an old rotary telephone. The four icons on the circle can be dragged with a finger to rotate all the icons (together) and when released, they settle with the icon nearest to the bottom, clicking into that bottom position, with it selected and the text underneath summarising that section. i.e. when the UI is not being dragged, there are only four positions it can be in (12pm, 3pm, 6pm, 9pm on the clock face).

I've not implemented a draggable UI like this before. How would I best go about it? Should I try to use MotionLayout, or monitor touch events, change the rotational position of the icon Views, and then on the up event, animate the rotation to "click" with the nearest icon at the bottom?

[image]

Comment: I found [this library](https://github.com/hongyangAndroid/Android-CircleMenu) , never checked it before myself so i cant tell how good it is

Answer (score 0):

I remembered that ConstraintLayout v1.1+ has a circular positional constraint which made the animation pretty simple. What wasn't so simple was handling the clicks, as I couldn't find any way to get them to pass through to the ImageViews below the draggable overlay View, so had to calculate which one had been clicked on. For anyone else looking to implement something like this, here's some code (note it uses Android Data Binding). The UI layout is responsible to screen sizes and resizes the icons as a % of the View UI.

This code doesn't support flings, or for the rotary dial to "lock" into specific positions, but both could be added with animations that begin after a drag has ended.

RotaryView.kt:

```
import android.content.Context
import android.util.AttributeSet
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.MotionEvent
import android.view.View
import android.widget.ImageView
import androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
import timber.log.Timber

/**
 * Displays a circle of icons that rotate and can be selected (if at the bottom position)
 * or clicked
 */
class RotaryView @JvmOverloads constructor(
    context: Context,
    attrs: AttributeSet? = null,
    defStyleAttr: Int = 0
) : ConstraintLayout(context, attrs, defStyleAttr) {

    private var binding: ViewRotaryBinding = ViewRotaryBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(context), this, true)
    private var callback: RotaryListener? = null

    fun setUp(callback: RotaryListener) {
        this.callback = callback
        callback.onNutritionSelected() // Default selection
        binding.dragOverlay.setOnTouchListener(DragListener())
    }

    override fun onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus: Boolean) {
        setConstraintRadius(binding.dashboardMind)
        setConstraintRadius(binding.dashboardFitness)
        setConstraintRadius(binding.dashboardNutrition)
        setConstraintRadius(binding.dashboardVirtualWorld)
    }

    /// Private methods

    private fun setConstraintRadius(view: View) {
        val layoutParams = view.layoutParams as ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams
        layoutParams.circleRadius = width / 3
        view.layoutParams = layoutParams
    }

    private fun rotateDialer(angleDelta: Float) {
        setIconAngle(binding.dashboardMind, angleDelta) { callback?.onMindSelected() }
        setIconAngle(binding.dashboardFitness, angleDelta)  { callback?.onFitnessSelected() }
        setIconAngle(binding.dashboardNutrition, angleDelta)  { callback?.onNutritionSelected() }
        setIconAngle(binding.dashboardVirtualWorld, angleDelta)  { callback?.onVirtualWorldSelected() }
    }

    private fun setIconAngle(imageView: ImageView, angleDelta: Float, showSummary: ()->Unit) {
        val layoutParams = imageView.layoutParams as ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams
        val newAngle = normaliseAngle(layoutParams.circleAngle.toInt() + angleDelta.toInt())
        if (newAngle in 136..224) showSummary() // Bottom quadrant
        layoutParams.circleAngle = newAngle.toFloat()
        imageView.layoutParams = layoutParams
    }

    private fun handleClick(angle: Int) {
        val clickAngle0to360 = normaliseAngle(90 - angle)
        val layoutParams = binding.dashboardMind.layoutParams as ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams
        val iconsAngle0to360 = normaliseAngle(layoutParams.circleAngle.toInt())
        val correctedAngle = normaliseAngle(clickAngle0to360 - iconsAngle0to360)
        when {
            (correctedAngle > (360-45) || correctedAngle < 45) -> callback?.onMindClicked()
            ((45) .. (90 + 45)).contains(correctedAngle) -> callback?.onFitnessClicked()
            ((180 - 45) .. (180 + 45)).contains(correctedAngle) -> callback?.onNutritionClicked()
            ((270 - 45) .. (270 + 45)).contains(correctedAngle) -> callback?.onVirtualWorldClicked()
            else -> Timber.e("Impossible state")
        }
    }

    private fun normaliseAngle(angle: Int) : Int {
        return (angle + 360).rem(360)
    }

    private inner class DragListener : OnTouchListener {

        private var startAngle: Double = 0.toDouble()
        private var shouldClick = true

        override fun onTouch(v: View, event: MotionEvent): Boolean {
            when (event.action) {

                MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN -> {
                    shouldClick = true
                    startAngle = getAngle(event.x.toDouble(), event.y.toDouble())
                }

                MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE -> {
                    val currentAngle = getAngle(event.x.toDouble(), event.y.toDouble())
                    rotateDialer((startAngle - currentAngle).toFloat())
                    startAngle = currentAngle
                    shouldClick = false
                    v.performClick() // Just here to avoid IDE warnings
                }

                MotionEvent.ACTION_UP -> {
                    if (shouldClick) {
                        val angle = getAngle(event.x.toDouble(), event.y.toDouble())
                        handleClick(angle.toInt())
                    }
                }
            }

            return true
        }

        private fun getAngle(xTouch: Double, yTouch: Double): Double {
            val x = xTouch - width / 2.0
            val y = height - yTouch - height / 2.0
            return when (getQuadrant(x, y)) {
                1 -> Math.asin(y / Math.hypot(x, y)) * 180 / Math.PI
                2 -> 180 - Math.asin(y / Math.hypot(x, y)) * 180 / Math.PI
                3 -> 180 + -1.0 * Math.asin(y / Math.hypot(x, y)) * 180.0 / Math.PI
                4 -> 360 + Math.asin(y / Math.hypot(x, y)) * 180 / Math.PI
                else -> 0.0
            }
        }

        private fun getQuadrant(x: Double, y: Double): Int {
            return if (x >= 0) {
                if (y >= 0) 1 else 4
            } else {
                if (y >= 0) 2 else 3
            }
        }

    }

    interface RotaryListener {
        fun onMindClicked()
        fun onMindSelected()
        fun onFitnessClicked()
        fun onFitnessSelected()
        fun onNutritionClicked()
        fun onNutritionSelected()
        fun onVirtualWorldClicked()
        fun onVirtualWorldSelected()
    }

}
```

view_rotary.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        >

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            >

        <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/dashboard_circle"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_dashboard_circle"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.9"
                app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.9"
                tools:ignore="ContentDescription"
                />

        <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/dashboard_mind"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_dashboard_mind"
                app:layout_constraintCircle="@+id/dashboard_circle"
                app:layout_constraintCircleRadius="120dp"
                app:layout_constraintCircleAngle="0"
                app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.3"
                app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.3"
                android:contentDescription="@string/dash_board_mind_content_description"
                />

        <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/dashboard_virtual_world"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_dashboard_virtual_world"
                app:layout_constraintCircle="@+id/dashboard_circle"
                app:layout_constraintCircleRadius="120dp"
                app:layout_constraintCircleAngle="270"
                app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.3"
                app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.3"
                android:contentDescription="@string/dashboard_virtual_world_content_description"
                />

        <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/dashboard_fitness"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_dashboard_fitness"
                app:layout_constraintCircle="@+id/dashboard_circle"
                app:layout_constraintCircleRadius="120dp"
                app:layout_constraintCircleAngle="90"
                app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.3"
                app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.3"
                android:contentDescription="@string/dashboard_fitness_content_description"
                />

        <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/dashboard_nutrition"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_dashboard_nutrition"
                app:layout_constraintCircle="@+id/dashboard_circle"
                app:layout_constraintCircleRadius="120dp"
                app:layout_constraintCircleAngle="180"
                app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.3"
                app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.3"
                android:contentDescription="@string/dashboard_nutrition_content_description"
                />

        <View
                android:id="@+id/dragOverlay"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:focusable="true"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/dashboard_circle"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/dashboard_circle"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/dashboard_circle"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/dashboard_circle"
                />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</layout>
```